# How to get a unique identifier for iphone and android

Tags: android, iphone, cordova

I need to get a unique number for every device for my cordova app (iOS/Android)  The ID must be the same when user closes the app or install a new version

I cannot used the UUID from the "cordova device plugin" because the UUID changes when the user upgrade to a new version so it wouldn't work for me.

I have tried generating a unique number and storing it on the phone. However, I run into an issue where the information is not persisted.

This happens when the user install the app and then remove the app from the background. Otherwise , the data is saved

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the serial number of the phone as a unique identifier

Comment: Thanks but the serial number method in the cordova-plugin-device" plugin is only avail for Android and  OSX platform ... not iOS...I need it for both iOS and Android. Is  there another option to get it for both platform

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to use [cordova-plugin-cloud-settings](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-cloud-settings) which allows you to persist user settings in cloud storage across devices and installs.

Install it:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-cloud-settings
```

Use it to store a GUID:

```
var settings = {
  GUID: 12345678
}
cordova.plugin.cloudsettings.save(settings);
```

The nice thing about this solution is it doesn't need any special user permissions.

If you really want a unique device ID (vs unique user ID) then you could use the [UniqueDeviceID](https://github.com/Paldom/UniqueDeviceID) plugin.

However, note that on Android this uses the SIM ID to obtain an identifier so [requires `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission](https://github.com/Paldom/UniqueDeviceID/blob/master/plugin.xml#L29) which displays a user permissions prompt "Allow to make and manage phone calls", which is not great for the trust of your users.

Answer (score 0):

Use the MAC address:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ip-mac-address
```

```
var params = {};
addressimpl.request("getMACAddress", JSON.stringify(params), function(message) {
        alert("mac address "+message);
   }, function() {
        alert("failed on get mac address");
    });
```

[From here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-ip-mac-address)